# Personal results for Actions on iPhones

Tags: actions-on-google

We just launched a new Action on Google “Share Now” which works great on android phones and the Google nest hub. However, when we try to open it on iPhones, we get this the following message:
`To let me read out that information, turn on personal results in the Google Home app.`

In the Google Home app, I have this setting for all my speakers, but I can’t find it for the phone. Googling also only shows results for the speakers and not the iPhone. Does anybody know where personal results can be turned on for iPhones?

Thanks!

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Is there something in `Settings > Google Home` or `Settings > Google Assistant` that might seem applicable?

Comment: Thanks Nick, after your comment I started my search in the assistant app and found the setting. Pretty sure this setting for iPhone isn't in the Google Home app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69105806/google-actions-on-the-assistant-app-on-iphone-no-longer-work for another description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Setting can be found in your Google Assistant app and not in the Google Home app. In the Assistant app Profile -> Devices -> iPhone (or name of your iPhone)