# Google Actions on the Assistant app on iPhone no longer work

Tags: ios, iphone, actions-on-google, google-assistant

Our Action has worked as expected for years on iPhone, but something changed and now access is blocked for our customers.

How to reproduce the issue: Simply go to Assistant on iPhone and say "Hey Google, talk to the mobile concierge" (our Action). Instead of launching the Action, Assistant says "I need permission before I can use your personal info for anything. To change your settings, just open the Google Home app on your phone. Once that's done, ask me again!".

My question: Can Google confirm that this is a bug and not expected behavior? (Specifically, that a user must have 'Personal Results' turned on in order to access an Action on iPhone.)

I truly hope this is not expected behavior, but even if it is there are 2 issues:

1. instructions that are provided to users when Personal Results are turned off are wrong. Pointing users to the Google Home app is incorrect. Many iPhone users won't even have the Google Home app installed. But if you do have it installed, launching it and then following Assistant's directions does not lead to being able to open the Action. The correct instructions are to stay in the Google Assistant app, click on your profile pic, go to Devices, and then select your iphone. There, you can turn Personal Results on/off.
2. The additional problem is that upon testing, I already had Personal Results turned ON. In order to get access to our Action, I had to turn it off, and then turn it back on again. So this pretty clearly seems like a bug.

As an aside, we don't collect any personal information as part of our Action so I am unclear why Google implemented a change involving the Personal Results option as it relates to the ability to launch Actions like ours. All it has done is made it so that our customers can't use it from a huge percentage of phones out there (iPhones), and phones are the only device we are targeting for use with this Action.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127004/personal-results-for-actions-on-iphones/69067052#69067052 for another example of this issue.

Comment: Google team, still an issue, any input is appreciated. @nickfelker